# How to avoid java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when iterating through and removing elements from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

I have an ArrayList that I want to iterate over. While iterating over it I have to remove elements at the same time. Obviously this throws a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

What is the best practice to handle this problem? Should I clone the list first?

I remove the elements not in the loop itself but another part of the code.

My code looks like this:

```
public class Test() {
    private ArrayList<A> abc = new ArrayList<A>();

    public void doStuff() {
        for (A a : abc) 
        a.doSomething();
    }

    public void removeA(A a) {
        abc.remove(a);
    }
}
```

`a.doSomething` might call `Test.removeA()`;

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html

Answer (score 431, accepted):

Two options:

- Create a list of values you wish to remove, *adding* to that list within the loop, then call  `originalList.removeAll(valuesToRemove)` at the end
- Use the `remove()` method on the iterator itself. Note that this means you can't use the enhanced for loop.

As an example of the second option, removing any strings with a length greater than 5 from a list:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
...
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    String value = iterator.next();
    if (value.length() > 5) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that i remove the elements in another part of the code and not the loop itself.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Well it's hard to answer without seeing how the two bits of code interact. Basically, you can't do that. It's not obvious whether cloning the list first would help, without seeing how it all hangs together. Can you give more details in your question?

Comment: I know that cloning the list would help, but I don't know if it is a good approach. But I'll add some more code.

Comment: @Roflcoptr Are you using more than one thread? If you are looping  while removing in code called in the loop, you need to loop over a copy of the list, or use a decreasing index, or use a list which does get CME.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: So could you just pass the iterator down instead? Why does `removeA` need to remove it *directly* from the collection? Does `removeA` even need to *know* about the rest of the collection? Could it actually just return a `boolean` to say whether or not it *should* be removed? Basically, the design of your code is encouraging problems here - calling arbitrary code which you don't control while iterating over a collection which can also be modified by other code is fundamentally problematic.

Comment: Cloning the list *may* be the best bet... but presumably `doSomething` could *also* add something to the list - how would you want that to be handled? Perhaps `doSomething` should be indicating that it wants something removed instead?

Comment: @JonSkeet doSomething() does not add something to the list, just possible remove it. I think cloning is a simple solution, but unfortunately i have a ugly cast then. Or is use a for loops that decrements through the list.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: But what if `doSomething()` decided to remove a *different* value from the list? There's a problem of encapsulation here, fundamentally. What's `doSomething` meant to do? Rather than it being able to remove items directly, could it decide whether or not the value *should* be removed, and let the iterating code do the removal?

Comment: @JonSkeet What do you mean by a different value? And why should it be a problem when using clone?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ok I think I've solved the problem. If I just use a for (int i ....) loop then I don't have this problem..

Comment: @JonSkeet small point: `originalList.removeAll()` has method signature `Collection` (rather than more specifically, `List`). So `valuesToRemove` could be, for example, a `List` or a `Set`.

Comment: This solution also leads to java.util.ConcurrentModificationException, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18448699/2914140.

Comment: @CoolMind: Um, no it doesn't. The answer you've linked to is equivalent to mine - what difference do you think there is?

Comment: @JonSkeet, you are right, but in my case it raised the exception, but another variant worked. Sorry.

Comment: @CoolMind: Without multiple threads, this code should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! My solution was a variation of option 1: cloned the List, iterated through one, changes made in the second, then return the second.

Comment: Cloning the list and make changes on it would work but this is the best option to avoid ConcurrentModificationException ( " Without multiple threads, this code should be fine" ) :-) thanks for share Mr. Skeet.

Comment: saving life with stack overflow answers since 2011

Answer (score 32):

From the JavaDocs of the ArrayList

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if  the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, **in any way except  through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods**, the iterator will throw a 
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: and where is the answer to the question ?

Comment: Like it says, *except through the iterator's own remove or add methods*

Answer (score 29):

You are trying to remove value from list in advanced "for loop", which is not possible, even if you apply any trick (which you did in your code).
Better way is to code iterator level as other advised here.

I wonder how people have not suggested traditional for loop approach.

```
for( int i = 0; i < lStringList.size(); i++ )
{
    String lValue = lStringList.get( i );
    if(lValue.equals("_Not_Required"))
    {
         lStringList.remove(lValue);
         i--; 
    }  
}
```

This works as well.

Comment: This is not correct!!! when you remove an element, the next is taking its position and while i increases the next element is not checked in the next iteration.
In this case you should go for( int i =  lStringList.size(); i>-1; i-- )

Comment: Agree! Alternate is to perform i--; in if condition within for loop.

Comment: I think this answer was edited to address the issues in the above comments, so as it is now it works fine, at least for me.

Comment: @KiraResari, Yes. I have updated the answer to address the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me in solving my problem :)

Answer (score 18):

In Java 8 you can use the Collection Interface and do this by calling the removeIf method:

```
yourList.removeIf((A a) -> a.value == 2);
```

More information can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)

Comment: in Android, Call requires API level 24 (Android Nougat)

Comment: It can still throw the same exception if called multiple times at once.

Answer (score 12):

You should really just iterate back the array in the traditional way

Every time you remove an element from the list, the elements after will be push forward. As long as you don't change elements other than the iterating one, the following code should work.

```
public class Test(){
    private ArrayList<A> abc = new ArrayList<A>();

    public void doStuff(){
        for(int i = (abc.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) 
            abc.get(i).doSomething();
    }

    public void removeA(A a){
        abc.remove(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

While iterating the list, if you want to remove the element is possible. Let see below my examples,

```
ArrayList<String>  names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("abc");
        names.add("def");
        names.add("ghi");
        names.add("xyz");
```

I have the above names of Array list. And i want to remove the "def" name from the above list,

```
for(String name : names){
    if(name.equals("def")){
        names.remove("def");
    }
}
```

The above code throws the **ConcurrentModificationException** exception because you are modifying the list while iterating.

So, to remove the "def" name  from Arraylist by doing this way,

```
Iterator<String> itr = names.iterator();            
while(itr.hasNext()){
    String name = itr.next();
    if(name.equals("def")){
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

The above code, through iterator we can remove the "def" name from the Arraylist and try to print the array, you would be see the below output.

Output :  [abc, ghi, xyz]

Comment: Else, we can use concurrent list which is available in concurrent package, so that you can perform remove and add operations while iterating. For example see the below code snippet.       ArrayList<String>  names = new ArrayList<String>();
  CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> copyNames = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>(names);
  
  for(String name : copyNames){
   if(name.equals("def")){
    copyNames.remove("def");
   }
  }

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList gonna be costliest operations.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of an `ArrayList`. This is the latest recommended approach by from JDK 1.5 onwards.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example where I use a different list to add the objects for removal, then afterwards I use stream.foreach to remove elements from original list :

```
private ObservableList<CustomerTableEntry> customersTableViewItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
...
private void removeOutdatedRowsElementsFromCustomerView()
{
    ObjectProperty<TimeStamp> currentTimestamp = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(TimeStamp.getCurrentTime());
    long diff;
    long diffSeconds;
    List<Object> objectsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
    for(CustomerTableEntry item: customersTableViewItems) {
        diff = currentTimestamp.getValue().getTime() - item.timestamp.getValue().getTime();
        diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        if(diffSeconds > 10) {
            // Element has been idle for too long, meaning no communication, hence remove it
            System.out.printf("- Idle element [%s] - will be removed\n", item.getUserName());
            objectsToRemove.add(item);
        }
    }
    objectsToRemove.stream().forEach(o -> customersTableViewItems.remove(o));
}
```

Comment: I think that you're doing extra work executing two loops, in worst case the loops would be of the entire list. Would be simplest and less expensive doing it in only one loop.

Comment: I do not think you can remove object from within first loop, hence the need for extra removal loop, also removal loop is only objects for removal - perhaps you could write an example with only one loop, I would like to see it - thanks @LuisCarlos

Comment: As you say with this code you can't remove any element inside the for-loop because it causes the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException exception. However you could use a basic for. Here I write an example using part of your code.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < customersTableViewItems.size(); i++) {
        diff = currentTimestamp.getValue().getTime() - customersTableViewItems.get(i).timestamp.getValue().getTime();
        diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        if(diffSeconds > 10) {
            customersTableViewItems.remove(i--);
        }
    }

Is important i-- because you don't want skip any elment.
Also you could use the method removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter) provided by ArrayList class.
Hope this help

Comment: @LuisCarlos, if this is possible, then why the exception when using the other way? perhaps this is not safe, anyway thanks for your example

Comment: The exception occurs because in for-loop there as an active reference to iterator of the list. In the normal for, there's not a reference and you have more flexibility to change the data.
Hope this help

Answer (score 5):

Do the loop in the normal way, the `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` is an error related to the elements that are accessed.

So try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    lista.get(i).action();
}
```

Comment: You avoided the `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` by not removing anything from the list. Tricky. :)
You can not really call this "the normal way" to iterate a list.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes old school is best. Just go for a simple for loop but make sure you start at the end of the list otherwise as you remove items you will get out of sync with your index.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if ("removeMe".equals(list.get(i))) {
    list.remove(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One option is to modify the `removeA` method to this -

```
public void removeA(A a,Iterator<A> iterator) {
     iterator.remove(a);
     }
```

But this would mean your `doSomething()` should be able to pass the `iterator` to the `remove` method. Not a very good idea.

Can you do this in two step approach : 
 In the first loop when you iterate over the list , instead of removing the selected elements , *mark* them as *to be deleted*. For this , you may simply copy these elements ( shallow copy ) into another `List`.

Then , once your iteration is done , simply do a `removeAll` from the first list all elements in the second list.

Comment: Excellent, I used the same approach, although I loop twice. it makes things simple and no concurrent issues with it :)

Comment: I don't see that Iterator has a remove(a) method. The remove() takes no arguments https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html what am I missing ?

Comment: @c0der is right. I mean how did this even get voted 5 times...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using For each loop, use normal for loop. for example,the below code removes all the element in the array list without giving java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. You can modify the condition in the loop according to your use case.

```
for(int i=0; i<abc.size(); i++)  {
       e.remove(i);
 }
```

Comment: I do not think this works. After removing the element at index 0 the second element becomes the first (index 0). In the next iteration we skip this element and remove the one at index 1. Plus, the original question was not how to remove all elements.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the accepted answer is not working, It stops Exception but it causes some inconsistency in my List. The following solution is perfectly working for me.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> itemsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

for (String value: list) {
   if (value.length() > 5) { // your condition
       itemsToRemove.add(value);
   }
}
list.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
```

In this code, I have added the items to remove, in another list and then used `list.removeAll` method to remove all required items.

Answer (score 3):

Do somehting simple like this:

```
for (Object object: (ArrayList<String>) list.clone()) {
    list.remove(object);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative Java 8 solution using stream:

```
        theList = theList.stream()
            .filter(element -> !shouldBeRemoved(element))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In Java 7 you can use Guava instead:

```
        theList = FluentIterable.from(theList)
            .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
                @Override
                public boolean apply(String element) {
                    return !shouldBeRemoved(element);
                }
            })
            .toImmutableList();
```

Note, that the Guava example results in an immutable list which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (A a : new ArrayList<>(abc)) {
    a.doSomething();
    abc.remove(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Should I clone the list first?"

That will be the easiest solution, remove from the clone, and copy the clone back after removal.

An example from my rummikub game:

```
SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void removeStones() {
  ArrayList<Stone> clone = (ArrayList<Stone>) stones.clone();
  // remove the stones moved to the table
  for (Stone stone : stones) {
      if (stone.isOnTable()) {
         clone.remove(stone);
      }
  }
  stones = (ArrayList<Stone>) clone.clone();
  sortStones();
}
```

Comment: Downvoters should at least leave a comment before downvoting.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with this answer expect maybe that `stones = (...) clone.clone();` is superfluous. Would not `stones = clone;` do the same?

Comment: I agree, the second cloning is unnecessary. You can futher simplify this by iterating on the clone and remove elements directly from `stones`. This way you do not even need the `clone` variable:

`for (Stone stone : (ArrayList<Stone>) stones.clone()) {...`

Answer (score 0):

I arrive late I know but I answer this because I think this solution is simple and elegant:

```
List<String> listFixed = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> dynamicList = new ArrayList<String>();

public void fillingList() {
    listFixed.add("Andrea");
    listFixed.add("Susana");
    listFixed.add("Oscar");
    listFixed.add("Valeria");
    listFixed.add("Kathy");
    listFixed.add("Laura");
    listFixed.add("Ana");
    listFixed.add("Becker");
    listFixed.add("Abraham");
    dynamicList.addAll(listFixed);
}

public void updatingListFixed() {
    for (String newList : dynamicList) {
        if (!listFixed.contains(newList)) {
            listFixed.add(newList);
        }
    }

    //this is for add elements if you want eraser also 

    String removeRegister="";
    for (String fixedList : listFixed) {
        if (!dynamicList.contains(fixedList)) {
            removeResgister = fixedList;
        }
    }
    fixedList.remove(removeRegister);
}
```

All this is for updating from one list to other and you can make all from just one list
and in method updating you check both list and can eraser or add elements betwen list.
This means both list always it same size

Answer (score 0):

Use Iterator instead of Array List

Have a set be converted to iterator with type match

And move to the next element and remove

```
Iterator<Insured> itr = insuredSet.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) { 
    itr.next();
    itr.remove();
}
```

Moving to the next is important here as it should take the index to remove element.

Answer (score 0):

**Very important**

ConcurrentModificationException can occur during `ArrayList<>` sorting, if the `ArrayList<>` sorting method is called at the same time, ie. parallel (asynchronous).

For example from two background `Thread`s, or `Thread` and `UI`, but at the same time. This usually happens by **accident**, if you drop the order of operations somewhere during programming.

Happened to me just now :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.addAll(OriginalList);

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.addAll(OriginalList);
```

This is also an option.

Answer (score -2):

If your goal is to remove all elements from the list, you can iterate over each item, and then call:

```
list.clear()
```

Answer (score -2):

What about of

```
import java.util.Collections;

List<A> abc = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Answer (score -2):

**ERROR**

There was a mistake when I added to the same list from where I took elements:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.mathList(_fun: (T) -> T): MutableList<T> {
    for (i in this) {
        this.add(_fun(i))   <---   ERROR
    }
    return this   <--- ERROR
}
```

**DECISION**

Works great when adding to a new list:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.mathList(_fun: (T) -> T): MutableList<T> {
    val newList = mutableListOf<T>()   <---   DECISION
    for (i in this) {
        newList.add(_fun(i))   <---   DECISION
    }
    return newList   <---   DECISION
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Just add a *break* after your *ArrayList.remove(A)* statement

Comment: Could you please add some explanation?