# Removing an object from an ArrayList throws Exception

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

```
/**
 * Write a mehod that removes the movie with a given title
 */
public void removeMovie(String title)
{
    for (Movie movie : movies){
        if(movie.getTitle().equals(title)){
            movies.remove(movie);
        }
    }
}
```

There is another class called Movie if anyone needs me to post it. This throws an exception though. Why?

Comment: It will throw a `ConcurrentModification Error` as @ScaryWombat said use an iterator

Comment: We can guess that you're getting a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), but you should always show the exact error you're getting, instead of just "I get an error", because that's pretty useless to us.

Comment: @Andreas yes that is the error i get, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to remove an element from a list youre looping through so it will throw a concurrent modification exception. There are a number of ways to get around this:

- use an iterator
- make a list of to be removed elements and add the elements you wish to remove to it in the loop and then remove all those elements from it afterwards
- use a for loop not a for each loop accounting for the shift when you remove an element (I.e. i--)
- loop backwards through the list
- probably others that I missed

Read solutions from here:
[How to avoid "ConcurrentModificationException" while removing elements from `ArrayList` while iterating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr)

Comment: it won't let me iterate since the ArrayList is made from another class and instead gives me `java.util.iterator<Movie> cannot be converted to java.util.iterator<java.lang.integer>` this is the method i wrote:     /**
     * Write a mehod that removes the movie with a given title
     */
    public void removeMovie(String title)
    {
        Iterator<Integer> itr = movies.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()){
            if(itr.next().equals(title)){
                itr.remove();
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Change Iterator<Integer> to Iterator<Movie> :)

Comment: Duh! what was I thinking. Although the method works it doesn't seem to remove anything...I also have a method called `printMovies()` and it still prints the movie I removed