# Iterator and while-loop vs for-loop vs for-each performance for getting elements of a list

Tags: java, list, loops

I'm new in programming
I've learned three ways of getting elements of a list
and i know each of them is good in a specific situation
but i want to know which one is better in overall ( performance )

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
            arrayList.add(i + 666);
        }


        Iterator<Integer> iterator = arrayList.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next() + "Iterator");
        }

        System.out.println("==============");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(i) + " for ");
        }

        System.out.println("==============");
        for (int i : arrayList) {
            System.out.println(i + " for each");
        }
    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: like the answers say: Don't trouble yourself with performance issues. you rarely have to think about performance. here is a 4th example for Java8: `arrayList.forEach(System.out::println)` or `arrayList.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item + " Java 8"))`

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it for yourself? Fill the lists with 100'000 elements and measure times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think about performances. It is extremely on a mirco-management level that you would not even notice it. Besides that an `Iterator` is needed for iterating over a `Collection`. The enhanced for loop is a syntactical sugar, but it does the same as the `Iterator`. The only difference is that you explicitly need a `Iterator` to modify the `Collection` while looping over it. See [How to avoid "ConcurrentModificationException" while removing elements from `ArrayList` while iterating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr)

And lastly the range based loop is a way to limit the number of iteration while the other ones iterate over the whole Collection (except you add some conditions inside the loop block)

Comment: if it won't affect the performance, then there's nothing to worry about
and I'll try to use the one that does what i want.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't compare them. You can't use all the styles all the time.

To start with, style 1 (`while (...)`) and style 3 (`for-each`) are same. Style 3 (`for-each`) uses  style 1 (`iterator` and `while`) internally.

If you want to do operations on the list while iterating use the `iterator` style.  It supports that.

You can't modify list  in style 2 (simple `for`). If you just want to read the list and do not want to do anything apart from it go with style 2.

After all it's getting element from the underlying array using index. In traditional for loop, you are passing the `index` and incase of iterator, it keep on incrementing itself (`index`) internally.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any specified loop to access the elements of an array. under different conditions different loops are useful. mostly while loop is used to access elements of a list. but again it depends on the situation when to use which loop...and you already have a better knowledge of the difference of loops

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i: arrayList){
    System.out.println(i + " for each");
}
```

is the same as

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = arrayList.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(iterator.next() + "Iterator");
}
```

It is just syntactic sugar.

This

```
for (int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(arrayList.get(i) + " for ");
}
```

is probably a little better, **but only for ArrayList**, but should not actually make measurable difference, as the Iterator doesn't do anything different than this. For **other List implementations** however, which don't have O(1) `get(int index)`, this is much worse (LinkedList).