# Slick2d not updating, ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, arraylist, slick2d

I was trying to recreate the start screen of AngryBirds where there are projectiles shooting in the background. I tried slick2d with the following code

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame game, int delta) throws SlickException {
    for (int a = 0; a < delta; a++) {
        if (pros.size() < 5) {
            pros.add(new MenuProjectile(Images.red[0]));
        }
        pros.iterator().forEachRemaining(p -> {
            if (p.getX() > gc.getWidth() || p.getY() > gc.getHeight()) {
                pros.remove(p);
            } else {
                p.update();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And slick2d gives me the error

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:904)
at startmenu.Menu.update(Menu.java:29)
at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.update(StateBasedGame.java:266)
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:663)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
at state.Angrybird.main(Angrybird.java:29)
Thu Mar 29 21:07:04 SGT 2018 ERROR:Game.update() failure - check the game code.
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.update() failure - check the game code.
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:669)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
    at state.Angrybird.main(Angrybird.java:29)
    enter code here
```

Supposed that if I use iterators, this error should not be thrown. Please help!

Comment: Instead of using an ArrayList try with a CopyOnWriteArrayList: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Comment: An iterator is no promise that you can not encounter a ConcurrentModificationException. You could try to keep all elements you want to add or remove in an additional list and after you finished iterating your "first" list you add or remove all elements from the other list.

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad How do I use another list? Do you mean that I clone the list and then add the list on to the original list? But how? Wouldn't that cause ConcurrentModificationException as well?

Comment: checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr