# android ConcurrentmodificationException?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
@Override
public void bleDataReceiverObserver(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
    Log.v("bleDataReceiverObserver", bluetoothDevice.getName());
    if (list.size() == 0)
        list.add(new BleData(bluetoothDevice, bluetoothDevice.getAddress(), bluetoothDevice.getName()));
    for (BleData bleData : list) {
        if (bleData.getAddress().equals(bluetoothDevice.getAddress())) {
            break;
        } else
            list.add(new BleData(bluetoothDevice, bluetoothDevice.getAddress(), bluetoothDevice.getName()));
    }
}
```

Bluetooth scan results are received directly through the receiver. However, the speed of coming in and saving to the list is so fast that exceptions are made. What should I do?

Comment: The problem is that you're calling list.add inside of the for loop that's iterating over list.

Answer (score 0):

From [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

When accessing a `List` item in a loop it's not allowed to edit that list. You are adding item to a list in a loop. If you really need it or you can't find any solution then use another `List` to add item

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr) thread to learn more.

You can use this code:

```
  boolean isFound = false;
  for (BleData bleData : list) {
    if (bleData.getAddress().equals(bluetoothDevice.getAddress())) {
        isFound = true;
    }
  } 

  if(!isFound){
       bluetoothDevice.getAddress(), bluetoothDevice.getName()));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of ArrayList. The simplest way to solve ConcurrentModificationException.

like this:

```
List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify and iterate through same list in for loop. Change your method as follows:

```
@Override
public void bleDataReceiverObserver(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
    Log.v("bleDataReceiverObserver", bluetoothDevice.getName());
    if (list.size() == 0)
        list.add(new BleData(bluetoothDevice, bluetoothDevice.getAddress(), bluetoothDevice.getName()));
    for (BleData bleData : list) {
        if (bleData.getAddress().equals(bluetoothDevice.getAddress())) {
            //Do some action on match
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Approve the answer if it was useful so that other can benefit to

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through an ArrayList  and modifying it at same time. That causes a ConcurrentModificationException, so don't do it.Build a "shadow" copy of the list that has everything you want it to have at the end, then call removeAll() and then addAll(newList) on the original list,  and modify new shadow copy in loop