# Why i get ConcurrentModificationException even using an Iterator?

Tags: java, dictionary, exception, iterator

I have 3 servers and a client sending messages. And i implement a BFT algorithm.
So i have this part of code

```
    int tam = 0;

    if (unordered.size() <= maxOrderSize) {
        tam = unordered.size();
    } else {
        tam = maxOrderSize;
    }
    HashMap<String, byte[]> prop = new HashMap<String, byte[]>(tam);

    Iterator<String> it = unordered.keySet().iterator();

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            String id = it.next();
            prop.put(id, unordered.get(id));
            it.remove();
            unordered.remove(id);

        }
    }
```

and during the runtime objects are imported and removed from my Map **unordered**. 
also i want to mention that unordered is defined:

```
    Map<String, byte[]> unordered = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, byte[]>());
```

But suddenly it creates this exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.remove(HashMap.java:1456)
at edu.bft.comm.layer.BatchControl.createOrderMessage(BatchControl.java:123)
at edu.bft.comm.layer.BatchControlTPM.run(BatchControlTPM.java:24)
```

Any idea why this happens?

**EDIT1:** I tried to remove that line:  unordered.remove(id);

and i got that error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1442)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1466)
at edu.bft.comm.layer.BatchControl.createOrderMessage(BatchControl.java:120)
at edu.bft.comm.layer.BatchControlTPM.run(BatchControlTPM.java:24)
```

**EDIT2:** Also i want to mention that while i iterate **unordered** ,some new objects may added, while new messages are coming from the client.

Comment: The whole `for`-loop seems unnecessary and wrong.   Wouldn't `while(it.hasNext(){ String id = it.next(); ...}` make a lot more sense?

Comment: Yes, it probably should be a while loop as Kevin suggets. 

Additionally, what you really want is an iteration over the `entrySet()` instead the `keySet()`. By using the wrong Iterator, you need to make a collection lookup within `prop.put(...)`. And maybe by using the entrySet's iterator, its `remove()` operation might work.

Comment: I update my first post check the full code. and edit2. Thanks

Comment: @KevinAnderson no i don't want to remove all the objects but just a specific number specified from **tam**

Comment: @MarcusK. check this output https://pastebin.com/eCFLd3Rn i added a print before the for loop and one print after for loop this output is with already remove the line  unordered.remove(id);

Answer (score 2):

You're modifying the Map yourself.

Remove this line:         `unordered.remove(id);`

From your edit, you're modifying the Map while iterating it so obviously it's the problem.

The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) said:

> The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in
>   the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration
>   over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove
>   operation), the results of the iteration are undefined.

And HashMap will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` as you see.

Comment: Ok i removed that line and i started again my program. for now it works ok. I will wait to see if it will end normally. Thanks

Comment: please check first post i updated it with what happened

Comment: My code run without problem. Did you post your full code?

Comment: You still have `            unordered.remove(id);` in your code

Comment: check EDIT1.. i described what happened after removing that line

Comment: From your EDIT2: You're modifying your map from another place?

Comment: Yes from an another method in that class where when i receive a new message i add it in unordered map

Comment: ok thanks. Meybe a solution is todecrease how fast clients send messages. Because when with a lesser messaging rate, I do not have this problem

Comment: If you're using your Map to exchange data like that then you're doing it wrong. You continuously put data to the Map but in the consumer side, you only iterate over it once.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and fix the root of the problem instead of applying a hotfix that "will do most of the time". Either change the implementation of your HashMap, or try to synchronize access to the HashMap via the `synchronized`keyword (if you really cannot change the Map's implementation type)...

Comment: unordered is defined like that:     Map<String, byte[]> unordered = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, byte[]>());

Comment: i changed it to ConcurrentHashMap<String, byte[]> unordered = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, byte[]>(); and i wait to see wthat will happen!

Comment: Using ConcurrentHashMap iterator will never throw ConcurrentModificationException but it's not guaranteed that the iterator see the update/new data incoming. So it's up to your decision

Comment: for now it works well. The project is about implementing a BFT algorithm. all messages removed from unordered are added to prop and then i send prop to the other servers...
Right now i have 2 clients sending a message every 50 milliseconds....it works well for now comparatively the  Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, byte[]>()) implementation i had before

Answer (score 0):

OK, after Edit2, I feel that another answer makes sense.

First of all: If you have a standard HashMap, it is not thread safe by default! So iterating over such a collection may always cause trouble if other threads concurrently modify it. Maybe adding new items won't cause an exception, maybe it will.

If you have the possibility to change the Map implementation of `unordered`, use something thread safe like a [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). This one won't have any trouble if someone modifies it while another thread iterates over its elements with an iterator - the iterator has its own collection of items which won't directly interfere with the original Map.

If you cannot change the implementation, you're in trouble...

Comment: for now unordered is:
    Map<String, byte[]> unordered = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, byte[]>()); and you say to change it to ConcurrentHashMap<String, byte[]> unordered = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, byte[]>();

Comment: Correct. And then re-think your application design: Do you have a producer-consumer problem? Does every put into `unsorted` need to be pushed into `prop`? If so, you definitely need a more complex solution...

Comment: The project is about implementing a BFT algorithm. all messages removed from unordered are added to prop and then i send prop to the other servers...

Comment: Wow, ok, that's a nice challenge. I hope you'll finally successfully complete your implementation. Or you might include an existing library which already implemented BFT. Whatever your final solution will be, it probably won't use the Map interface anymore..

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) prevented:

> For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

In general, you cannot modify the collection when the iterator is iterating.
See the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr).