# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException Error while trying to use iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, tostring

I am writing a program where I create an `ArrayList`, and I want to traverse the list with an iterator:

```
ArrayList<Person> flightAttendants = new ArrayList<Person>();
Iterator<Person> itr = flightAttendants.iterator();
```

Here is how I am trying to traverse the elements of the arraylist:

I have defined a `toString` method too:

```
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(itr.next());
}

public String toString()
{
    System.out.println("name of the passenger : "+name);
    System.out.println("Age of the passenger : "+age);
    System.out.println("Seat number of the passenger : "+seatNumber);
    return "\n";            
}
```

Whenever I try to run it, it gives me the error: **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**

Where is the error here?

Update: here is the full code:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Person
{
    Integer age;
    String name;
    String seatNumber;
    Integer fare;
    int pnr;
    Person()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the passenger");
            name = b.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the age of the passenger");
            age = Integer.parseInt(b.readLine());
            System.out.println("Enter the Seat Number you want");
            seatNumber = b.readLine();
            pnr = (int)(Math.random()*100000000);
            System.out.println("PNR number of the passenger is : "+pnr);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("");         
        }
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        System.out.println("name of the passenger : "+name);
        System.out.println("Age of the passenger : "+age);
        System.out.println("Seat number of the passenger : "+seatNumber);
        return "\n";                
    }
}
class EconomyPassenger extends Person
{

}
class BusinessPassenger extends Person
{

}
class Crew extends Person
{

}
public class Airline
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<Person> flightAttendants = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Iterator<Person> itr = flightAttendants.iterator();
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Welcome to Indigo!!!");
                BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println("Enter your Choice");
                System.out.println("1.Book Tickets");
                System.out.println("2.Check Reservation");
                System.out.println("3.Update Tickets");
                System.out.println("4.Exit");
                int choice=Integer.parseInt(b.readLine());
                if(choice<0 || choice>4)
                {
                    throw new InvalidChoiceException("Enter a valid choice between 1 and 4");
                }
                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1: System.out.println("\n\n1.Economy*******2.Business*******3.Crew Login*******4.Exit");
                    // BufferedReader c = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    int c = Integer.parseInt(b.readLine());
                    if(c==1)
                    {
                        flightAttendants.add(new EconomyPassenger());
                    }
                    else if(c==2)
                    {
                        flightAttendants.add(new BusinessPassenger());
                    }
                    else if(c==3)
                    {
                        flightAttendants.add(new Crew());
                    }
                    else if(c==4)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                    case 2: // System.out.println("Enter your PNR Number : ");
                    // int p = Integer.parseInt(b.readLine());
                    // System.out.println(p);
                    while(itr.hasNext())
                    {
                        System.out.println(itr.next());
                    }
                    break;
                    case 3: System.out.println("case 3");break;
                    case 4: return;
                    default: System.out.println("default");
                }
            }    
            catch(InvalidChoiceException ic)
            {
                // System.out.println(ic);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
class InvalidChoiceException extends Exception
{
    InvalidChoiceException()
    {}
    InvalidChoiceException(String msg)
    {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: the toString method has been added in a class and there are no errors in the program except this one

Comment: Is your app multi thread?

Comment: From your current code we can't guess what is happening, could you provide a [mcve]  ?

Comment: You may need to show Person Class fully and main function where you are instantiating person class and flow of it

Comment: i have added the complete code for reference...thanks for asking..No @Sun my app does not has multithreading..

Comment: Side bar:  `toString()` should return all of that text instead of using `println()` within `toString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code being provided by you should work fine as I have tried it. Unless you show there is something else your code is working upon we cant further try to solve. I suggest you the check the question [Iterators and the concurrentmodificationexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr) also for better understanding that your code may be somewhere falling into errors mentioned there.

As mentioned by Andrew bring the iterator into your while loop and thats working fine check now. I tried it.

Comment: it works fine until you select the display function...add one or two passengers..and then go to display option..you will find the exception..By display i mean check reservation..

Comment: The iterator is created above the while loop, so on the next iteration which adds (modifies) to the list the iterator is no longer valid resulting in the exception.  Move the creation of the iterator to just before it's used.