# ConcurrentModificationException in TrafficUpdaterImpl, Android HERE SDK Version: 3.12.4.93

Tags: android, here-api

This is basically an FYI to here-api team, I've just had a fatal crash in my custom Android app using HERE SDK Version: 3.12.4.93

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  277): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1184
E/AndroidRuntime(  277): Process: com.navdy.hud.app, PID: 277
E/AndroidRuntime(  277): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
E/AndroidRuntime(  277):    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:787)
E/AndroidRuntime(  277):    at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:819)
E/AndroidRuntime(  277):    at com.nokia.maps.el.run(TrafficUpdaterImpl.java:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(  277):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/AndroidRuntime(  277):    Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: HERE SDK Version: 3.12.4.93
E/AndroidRuntime(  277):        at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$l.uncaughtException(MapsEngine.java:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(  277):        at net.hockeyapp.android.ExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(ExceptionHandler.java:200)
```

Not expecting a fix to be possible from my app code seeing as this is clearly happening on a thread inside the SDK, hopefully it doesn't happen too often!

Comment: Hope this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr

Comment: Thanks, but what I probably didn't make clear in the original post is the crash comes from the closed source SDK code so it's out of my reach to fix the iterator myself.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this. Our engineering team is looking into it.

Comment: Thank you for reporting! Should be fixed in SDK 3.14 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should have been fixed with SDK version 3.14 as mentioned in the comments. SDK version 3.14 is available now from HERE developer portal (https://developer.here.com/)