# Simple ArrayList.remove(int) doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I am trying to iterate through an `ArrayList` and remove the actual object (index s) under certain conditions (`x == 0`). It always gives an error at the line where the object should be removed, if executed. Without the `remove()` it runs perfectly fine.

```
int s = 0;
int x = 0;
if (!objectList.isEmpty()) {
    for (obj actualObj : objectList) {
        if (x == 0) {
            objectList.remove(s);
        } else {
            System.out.println("x != 0");
        }
        s++;
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("list is empty");
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You don't need to iterate to remove an element if you already know its index

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr

Comment: What are `x` and `s` here? they seem to always be `0`, and aren't effected by the loop

Comment: your code seems logicaly faulted, maybe you do not get the logic behind what you want to achieve, anyway see https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/arraylist-remove-example/

Comment: May be better use an iterator.

Comment: What's `obj`? A custom type?

Comment: Ok, thanks @all, solved my problem by simple pasting "break;" after the "remove()" AND replacing "s" by "actualObject". Works like a charm. For everyone who doesn't understand the logic: I didn't posted the whole code of 200 lines, only the part that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

My biggest nitpick would be this: you can't mutate/modify the collection you are iterating over (outside of calling `Iterator#remove`, etc) when using syntactic sugar like the enhanced for-each loop (`for (T val : Iterable<T>)`). In fact, `Iterator#remove` exists pretty much exactly for this reason:

```
int toRemove = 0; //The number to remove from your list
List<Integer> list = /* your list */;
Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator(); //Create an iterator of the collection
while (itr.hasNext()) { //while new elements are available...
    Integer val = itr.next(); //grab the next available element
    if (val == toRemove) { //removal condition
        itr.remove(); //remove the last grabbed element from the collection
    }
}
```

If you're capable of using Java 8:

```
int toRemove = 0; //The number to remove from your list
List<Integer> list = /* your list */;
list.removeIf(val -> toRemove == val); //didn't use member reference, for clarity reasons
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you remove an element from a `List` using an index, the `List` shrinks because the succeeding elements shift one place left/down. It means that in the next iteration of the loop, you will be actually deleting an element which was next to the next of the last deleted element.

For this reason, you should delete elements from a `List` in a loop using an `Iterator` instead of the index as shown below:

```
Iterator<YourType> itr = objectList.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    YourType obj = itr.next();
    if (some condition) {
        itr.remove();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are removing from the list while iterating through it. A workable option is

```
    int x = 0;
    List<String> objectList = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    if (objectList.isEmpty()) System.out.println("list is empty");

    List<String> filtered = objectList.stream().filter(s1 -> x != 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(objectList + "\n" + filtered);
```