# Move element of arraylist to last position

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList of complex objects `Box`. I need a specific element of these Boxes to be moved to the last position of the arrayList and have the original one removed like shown in the diagram:

[image]

My code is something like this, but I get this error: `ConcurrentModificationException`

```
for (Box i : boxes) {  //where boxes is the arrayList
 if (i.mouseOver()) {  //does the swapping I need if the mouse is over the box
  
  Box copy=i;
  boxes.remove(i);  //these 3 lines are where I think the mistake is
  boxes.add(copy);
 }
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are trying to modify a `Collection` on which you are iterating. You have to create a new `Collection` and modify that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid "ConcurrentModificationException" while removing elements from \`ArrayList\` while iterating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr)

Comment: Never use a *for-each* loop to modify a Java list! I suggest you to look at [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re), which explains your problem and their solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you modify the `boxes` (by removing and or adding elements) you cannot continue iterating over it.  One way you can avoid that would be by `break`ing out of the loop once you move the `Box` you want to move:

```
for (Box i : boxes) {  //where boxes is the arrayList
    if (i.mouseOver()) {  //does the swapping I need if the mouse is over the box
        // No need to create a new reference
        boxes.remove(i);
        boxes.add(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this would create `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: Then you are wrong, @Turtle.  Try it and see.  The CME comes from attempting to continue the iteration after the list is modified (which this avoids, but the OP's does not), not from the modifications themselves.

Comment: Okay, saw that...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove entries while in a for-each loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
    if (boxes.get(i).mouseOver())
        boxes.add(boxes.remove(i));
}
```

Comment: This will be a never-ending `loop`

Comment: @Turtle Nope, I tested it, and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` is the error you were getting,
try not to use advanced for loop and just use regular for loop. Also in your code I see you are trying to remove the element from the list with the actual object. In Arraylist you can only remove by the index, not the element.

I think below should work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
    if (boxes.get(i).mouseOver()) { 
        boxes.add(boxes.remove(i));
    }
}
```