# Error with java.util.ConcurrentModification while adding one bookmark

Tags: java, android

I got problem when i add the last 7st item position, other 6 items work perfectly with auto removes whenhasEnded. I cant add the 7st item, and when i got other items like 1-6 and adding the 7st item my application got error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

one the code:

```
 public List<LiveTvProgram> getLiveTvBookmarks() {
    String name = context.getString(R.string.preferences_bookmarks_live_tv);
    Set<String> bookmarks = preferenceHelper.getStringSet(name, name);
    ArrayList<LiveTvProgram> bookmarkList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String title : bookmarks) {
        for (LiveTvProgram program : ChannelsManager.getInstance().getSelectedPrograms()) {
            if (program.getTitle().equals(title)) {
                if (program.hasEnded()) {
                    bookmarks.remove(title);
                } else {
                    bookmarkList.add(program);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return bookmarkList;
}
```

With first for loop

```
for (String title : bookmarks) {
        for (LiveTvProgram program : ChannelsManager.getInstance().getSelectedPrograms()) {
            if (program.getTitle().equals(title)) {
                if (program.hasEnded()) {
                    bookmarks.remove(title);
                } else {
                    bookmarkList.add(program);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this exception because you are trying to modify the list `bookmarks` while you are iterating over it by calling `bookmarks.remove(title)`. Please have a look at the answer of this question to see how to avoid that:
[How to avoid java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when iterating through an removing elements from an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104692)

On a side note: Are you sure that you really need to remove items from the `bookmarks` list at all? You generate that list in your method by calling

```
Set<String> bookmarks = preferenceHelper.getStringSet(name, name);
```

and as you do not do anything with this list after you iterate over it may be you could just drop removing.

**UPDATE:** A quick general suggestion to rewriting your loops:

```
for (LiveTvProgram program : ChannelsManager.getInstance().getSelectedPrograms()) {
    //Check if this program is in your bookmarks. As bookmarks is 
    //a Set, contains should be quite efficient
    if (bookmarks.contains(program.getTitle()) {                
        bookmarkList.add(program);
        //further improvement: you could check here if all bookmarks 
        //have been matched and exit the loop if yes
    }
}
```

If you really need to clean your `bookmarks` list, you need to retain all entries which are not included in `bookmarkList` after this loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate on a list and modify it, it will always lead to ConcurrentModificationException.

So your code is incorrect, you cannot iterate over bookmarks and remove one of it's elements in the loop.

```
for (String title : bookmarks) {
        for (LiveTvProgram program : ChannelsManager.getInstance().getSelectedPrograms()) {
            if (program.getTitle().equals(title)) {
                if (program.hasEnded()) {
                    bookmarks.remove(title);//FORBIDDEN !!!
                } else {
                    bookmarkList.add(program);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED with a working example :**

```
    List<String> bookmarksToRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String title : bookmarks) {
            for (LiveTvProgram program : ChannelsManager.getInstance().getSelectedPrograms()) {
                if (program.getTitle().equals(title)) {
                    if (program.hasEnded()) {
                        bookmarksToRemoved.add(title);//keep them in a temporary list
                    } else {
                        bookmarkList.add(program);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    bookmarks.removeAll(bookmarksToRemoved);//remove all bookmarks to be removed
```

Regards,

Loïc

Comment: Hello, Do you have maybe any example how to do this correctly?

Comment: You should copy the bookmarks to be removed in a temporay List and removing them after the loop. I will edit my answer to reflect that

Comment: Yea this working, i thinking about making 2nd list with removing items and updating my first list with changes

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove the item of the list which you are iterating with in for each loop. So please ignore this for better solutions.