# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when adding/removing SubLists from/to lists

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, iterator

I'm adding/removing Items to/from ArrayLists in my app in the following way:

```
public long gotoItem(int pos) {
  if (pos > 0) {
      List<QueueItem> mSubList = mItems.subList(0, pos);

      switch (mRepeatType) {
          case NO_REPEAT:
          case REPEAT_SINGLE:
              mPlayedItems.addAll(mSubList);

              mItems.removeAll(mSubList);
              break;
          case REPEAT_ALL:
              mItems.removeAll(mSubList);

              mItems.addAll(mSubList);
              break;
      }
  }

  return (long) mItems.get(0).getItem();
}
```

I get the following exception thrown:

```
> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:314)
                                                               at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.iterator(AbstractList.java:301)
                                                               at java.util.AbstractCollection.contains(AbstractCollection.java:127)
                                                               at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(AbstractCollection.java:277)
                                                               at at.guger.musixs.playback.queue.Queue.gotoItem(Queue.java:135)
                                                               at at.guger.musixs.playback.MusicService.gotoPosition(MusicService.java:500)
                                                               at at.guger.musixs.playback.MusicPlayer.gotoPosition(MusicPlayer.java:138)
                                                               at at.guger.musixs.activity.MainActivity.SyncLocation(MainActivity.java:707)
                                                               at at.guger.musixs.activity.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:73)
                                                               at at.guger.musixs.activity.MainActivity$1.onServiceConnected(MainActivity.java:605)
                                                               at at.guger.musixs.playback.MusicPlayer$ServiceBinder.onServiceConnected(MusicPlayer.java:246)
                                                               at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1224)
                                                               at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1241)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Why does this error occur here and how can I fix this error in the simplest way?? - Do I really have to make a loop removing (and adding) the items from/to the arraylists?

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104692/how-to-avoid-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-when-iterating-through-an?rq=1

Comment: @IvanPronin I know this question but I'm not really looking for an iterator example if not really necessary!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SubList` is actually a view on top of the original list. Internally it still holds the original list. So when you call `originalList.removeAll(subList)`, internally it actually iterates over the original list and also tries to modify it. This is why you get `ConcurrentModificationException`.
A simple solution is to copy the sub-list to a new list (simplified example):

```
List<QueueItem> subList = new ArrayList<>(items.subList(0, pos));
items.removeAll(subList);
```

Comment: Ok, I understand! Thank you!