# Entity Component System removing entity

Tags: java, design-patterns

This is my first attempt to implement Entity Component System in my project and I'm not sure how some of its mechanics works. For example do I remove an entity? Since all systems are using entities list throughout whole game loop, every attempt of deleting element of that list is condemned to ConcurrentModificationException. Going by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104692/how-to-avoid-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-when-iterating-through-an?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) advice I've tried to setting some kind of "toRemove" flag for entities and look for it every time system iterate through list

```
public class DrawingSystem extends System {

    public DrawingSystem(List<Entity> entityList) {
        super(entityList);
    }

    public void update(Batch batch) {
        for (Entity entity : entityList) {
            removeIfNeccesarry(entity);
            //code

            }
        }

        public void removeIfNeccesarry(Entity entity){
            if(entity.toRemove){
                entityList.remove(entity);
            }
        }

    }
```

but that didn't help getting rid of the exception. I'm sure there is a elegant solution to this problem since this design pattern is broadly used but I'm just not aware of it.

Comment: The reason you're still getting a CME is because you're still removing the entity from `entityList` in the middle of iterating through it.  Have a look here for a solution: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-best-remove-an-entity-from-my-game-loop-when-it-is-dead

Answer (score 0):

Check out iterators:
"Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics."
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Iterator.html

```
    Iterator<Entity> it = entityList.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entity entity = it.next();

        if (...) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
```

You could also store the indices of the entities to remove somewhere outside the list and then remove the dead entities in an extra step after the update/render.
This has the advantage that you do not miss entities in later steps of your update.

Edit: Added code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although your answer is correct, it is always encouraged to put some code examples in your answers. Codes helps grabbing the attention over a too wordy answers.