# How do I implement a deep clone method with an ArrayList type variable

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans, clone

I'm trying to create a deep clone method, but the class contains an ArrayList type variable. I need to be able to deep clone it.

The class is called Major, and these are the two variables:

```
 private String mName;
private ArrayList<Subject> mCores;
```

And so far my method for the deep clone is this:

```
@Override
protected Major clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Major major = (Major) super.clone();
    for (Subject s : mCores) {
        Subject s1 = (Subject) s.clone();
        major.mCores.add(s1);
    }
    return major;
}
```

However i'm getting an error

```
at testStudentSystem.Major.clone(Major.java:52)
```

How can I implement this deep clone of the major class. Thank you.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)
 at testStudentSystem.Major.clone(Major.java:52)

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104692/how-to-avoid-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-when-iterating-through-an

Comment: I need to specifically use the clone method I created "protected Major clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{", I just don't know what to do inside the method, since there's an arraylist. If the variables mCores was type Subject, it would have been much more straightforward, but i'm limited to strictly using the ArrayList<Subject> mCores, and implement that inside the method to deep clone the major subject.